# Execute PHP Code via Ajax Call in drupal module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I was trying to convert [this](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) into a Drupal module so that I can check PHP code instantly on my site for debugging purposes.  I saw this Firefox add on which allows you to execute PHP on the fly but admin log in is necessary, so far I did everything , have one form and set up ajax calls , but if I pass a string like:

```
preg_match($pat,$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

How to execute this in backend?

**EDIT**

To load the form:

```
$items['localphp'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'executePHP',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

function executePHP(){
  $output = drupal_get_form('executePHP_form');
  return $output;
}
```

Ajax callback function:

```
$items['runPHP'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'getResult',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
function getResult(){
  $code = $_POST['code'];
  //I need help here how to execute $code i.e the php code and return back result
  echo $code;
}
```

JS function

```
function executePHP(baseurl){
  var code = $("#edit-code").val();
  $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : baseurl+'runPHP',
      data : 'code='+code,
      async : true,
      cache : false,
      success : function (res) {
        $("#edit-result").html(res);
      },
      error : function (res) {
        alert("error");
      }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Never Mind , i think eval() was what i was looking for.

Comment: Ah yea, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) has a feature that allows admins to run custom PHP code from their page.  The Devel module has a block with a ton of features useful for debugging.

For a custom module, without seeing any of your other code, I can tell you what I have done to achieve AJAX in a Drupal module:

In JavaScript make an AJAX request to a url on your site.  Add a menu item with the specified path inside of `hook_menu()` as `'type' => MENU_CALLBACK` that points to a function in your module.  This function should do all the processing you need, then return the results to JavaScript to do what you want with it there.

Comment: devel is not ajax i think i used long back forgot , i will look into that to get the idea , i have set up ajax and all as i mentioned the thing where i got stuck is like this , i am getting php code to the ajax function and then how to proceed ? how to execute that php code like the one mentioned and return result ?

Comment: Show _how_ you are doing the AJAX, not just the PHP you want to execute.  I will be able to look at it in the morning and possibly provide an example of what I used.